# MFMailComposeViewController: Attaching Images from Photo Gallery

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, alassetslibrary, messageui

I am having a bit of trouble attaching images from the Photo Gallery to an email.

Basically, one of the features of my application allow the user to take photos.  When they snap the shot, I record the URL Reference to the image in Core Data.  I understand that you have to go through the `ALAssetRepresentation` to get to the image.  I have this up and running within my application for when the user wants to review an image that they have taken.

I am now attempting to allow the user to attach all of the photos taken for an event to an email.  While doing this, I iterate through the Core Data entity that stores the URL References, call a method that returns a `UIImage` from the `ALAssetsLibrary` and then attaches it using the `NSData`/`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and `MFMailComposeViewController`/`addAttachmentData` methods.

Problem is: When the email is presented to the user, there are small blue squares representing the images and the image is not attached.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)sendReportReport
{

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Log: Report"];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"someone@someco.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];


        NSError *error;

        NSFetchRequest *fetchPhotos = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                       entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
        [fetchPhotos setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *fetchedPhotos = [__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchPhotos error:&error];
        int counter;

        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in fetchedPhotos ) {
            Photo *photo = (Photo *)managedObject;

//            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", counter++]];
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self getImage:photo.referenceURL], 0.5);
//            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self getImage:photo.referenceURL]);
//            [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counter]];  
            [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a.jpg"]];  

            counter++;

        }


        NSString *emailBody = [self getEmailBody];

        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }

}
```

and the method that returns the `UIImage`:

```
#pragma mark - Get Photo from Asset Library
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library; 
}

- (UIImage *)getImage:(NSString *)URLReference
{

    __block UIImage *xPhoto = nil;

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        UIImage *xImage;

        // get the image
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];

        if (iref) {
            xImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        }

        xPhoto = xImage;

    };


    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching photo: %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    };


    NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:URLReference];

    // create library and set callbacks
    ALAssetsLibrary *al = [DetailsViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];
    [al assetForURL:asseturl 
        resultBlock:resultblock
       failureBlock:failureblock];   

    return xPhoto;

}
```

NOTE: This above code does run, it simply does not attach the image.  Also, note, I am able to successfully attach images from the gallery within my application, as long at I have set them into a `UIImageView`.Image already (basically, I am taking the pointer to the image from the `UIImageView` and passing it to the `addAttachmentData` method.)  It is just when I attempt to iterate through Core Data and attach without first setting the image into a `UIImageView` that I have the trouble.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: Have you printed the contents of the image, before adding it as an attachment? (`CFShow([self getImage:photo.referenceURL]);`) Perhaps it is nil at this point?

Comment: Hi Jaydee, my guess is that you are correct.  It is likely nil.  But, what should I do?  Am I approaching this in the wrong way, but creating a method that returns a UIImage? Should I do something different to iterate through my list of URL References to Photo Gallery images?

Comment: just go up to find the error. If the image is nil, than your reference URL is wrong obviously. So check how the URL is created..

Comment: The reference URL is NOT wrong. As I stated in my original post, I am able to successfully render the image from the reference URL in another view within my application. As you guessed the image is nil, but I am not understanding why. I think that it has something to do with returning the UIImage via the return of the method.  If you are knowledgable about ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock I'd appreciate if you'd look at the getImage method and let me know if you see anything that would cause the image to be returned as nil. I did see the image with cfshow, but it's not returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh now I see it.. sry. You are using an asynchronous block to get the image from the asset library. But right after starting that operation, you are returning `xImage`. But the asynchronous operation will finish later. So you are returning nil.

You need to change your architectur to smth like this:

In your .h file you need two new members:

```
NSMutableArray* mArrayForImages;
NSInteger mUnfinishedRequests;
```

In your .m file do smth like that:

```
- (void)sendReportReport
{
    // save image count
    mUnfinishedRequests = [fetchedPhotos count];

    // get fetchedPhotos
    [...]

    // first step: load images
    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in fetchedPhotos )
    {
        [self loadImage:photo.referenceURL];    
    }
}
```

Change your getImage method to loadImage:

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)URLReference
{
    NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:URLReference];

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {    
        // get the image
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];

        if (iref) {
            [mArrayForImages addObject: [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref]];
        } else {
            // handle error
        }

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(imageRequestFinished)];
    };

    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching photo: %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(imageRequestFinished)];
    };


    // create library and set callbacks
    ALAssetsLibrary *al = [DetailsViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];
    [al assetForURL:asseturl 
        resultBlock:resultblock
       failureBlock:failureblock];
}
```

Create a new callback method:

```
- (void) imageRequestFinished
{
    mUnfinishedRequests--;
    if(mUnfinishedRequests <= 0)
    {
       [self sendMail];
    }
}
```

And an extra method for finally sending the mail, after getting the images:

```
- (void) sendMail
{
    // crate mailcomposer etc
    [...]

    // attach images
    for (UIImage *photo in mArrayForImages )
    {
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.5);
                [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a.jpg"]];
    }

    // send mail
    [...]
}
```

Comment: This is great Jaydee!!!  Let me try it out and then I will mark this answered.  Thanks for you help.  I do appreciate your time.

Comment: I really can't figure out what is wrong, but for some reason the array doesn't get any objects added.  There are two images recorded in Core Data, the CFImageRef is called twice, when I look at CFShow(iref) I get <CGImage 0x8dd4fb0>, but when I look at CFShow(mArrayForImages) I get (null).  Your architecture looks really sound, but for some reason the object isn't being added to the array.  It is actually similar to what was happening when my method was being called.

Comment: I just created another brand new view with two UIImageView controls and a UIButton and was able to successfully display the images from Core Data URL References in the UIImageView.  I am really stumped.

Comment: you have to initalise the array first :) `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` and of course release it in your `dealloc`.

Comment: Thanks Jaydee!  Makes complete sense and kinda obvious now that I think of it.  I should have thought of that.  I will try it when I get home.  If I am using ARC, do I still need to "dealloc"?

Comment: No, with ARC you dont need to release it again. Just initialise it.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to say thanks for helping me with this.  I appreciate your time.  The approach you laid out was perfect.  Thanks again Jaydee!